# the "unit speed" anlogue of the evolute of the curve

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a curve, $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ define the flow in the normal direction by $\gamma(t) + \epsilon \, \mathbf{n}(t)$.  This is different from the [evolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) which moves at speed proportional to the radius of curvature.

**Example**:  The unit square with edge thickness, moves inwards, but the corners move diagonally.

If the polygon is piecewise linear, how to the cusps move under this unit speed flow?

---

For my application, $\gamma(t)$ is a *polygon* in the Euclidean plane, not necessarily convex.  The points are $ \{ (a_1, b_1), \dots, (a_n, b_n)\} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  I need to account for the thickness of the boundary.  The result is a polygon which is almost the same: $ \{ (a_1 \pm \epsilon , b_1\pm \epsilon), \dots, (a_n\pm \epsilon, b_n\pm \epsilon)\} \in \mathbb{R}^2$. 
How do I compute the envelope in this case?

[image]

This is similar to Ravi Vakil's [The Mathematics of Doodling](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/monthly116-129-vakil.pdf).  In fact, I have even drawn the "unit-speed evolute" in this case...

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @JosephZambrano you draw a polygon in the plane with a thick smudgy pen.  what are the coordinates of the interior?

Comment: Oh I see. As you said, we can first draw a polygon and then at each point, add a vector of length $\epsilon$ pointing in the normal direction. I suppose at the sharp edges we can always choose a vector which faces away from the interior of the polygon. In some sense, it just seems like scaling the polygon.

Comment: @JosephZambrano the square is a misleading example. if we rescale a polygon we need to specify a **center** and the rescaling changes depending on our choice.  i need to move around the perimeter and carve out thickness $\varepsilon$ from the sides.

Answer (score 1):

Pez, if I understand correctly, you want to know how each polygon vertex $v = (a_i,b_i)$ moves as you move each edge along the edge normal by $\epsilon$?

First, compute the normals $N_1, N_2$ of the two edges adjacent to $v$. Then the inflated vertex position $v'$ is given by

$$v' = v + \frac{N_1+N_2}{\|N_1+N_2\|} \epsilon \sec \frac{\psi}{2},$$
where $\psi$ is the angle between the normals (see the diagram at https://www.dropbox.com/s/glpwplrtim8fkl7/kites.pdf). Applying the cosine half-angle formula I get

$$v' = v + \frac{(N_1+N_2)\epsilon\sqrt{2}}{\|N_1+N_2\|\sqrt{1+N_1\cdot N_2}} = v + \frac{(N_1+N_2)\epsilon}{1+N_1\cdot N_2}.$$

As a sanity check, notice that $(v'-v)\cdot N_1 = \epsilon$ and likewise for $N_2$.

Comment: Okay.  In my graphic, I naïvely averaged the two normals $\frac{1}{2}(N_1 + N_2)$, allowing me to smoothly deform the contour and yet retain the overall shape.  All my angles are very "bent" - close to $90^\circ$ - and so $N_1 \cdot N_2 \approx 0$.